# When combining rasters how to reduce heights of regions having height above a limit in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem

I am trying to use DEMs extracted from USGS earth explorer, in my DEM there is a plane region (Ganga Planes) adjacent to high mountains (Himalayas). While combining DEMs of that region I want that if any region has a height above a certain limit, it should be compressed and not clipped. A height above 2000m should be non-linearly represented in the combined raster.

I do not want to clip the area above a certain height but I want to compress the profile.

I have seen another post having this formula Con("myraster" > 2000, 1800, "myraster").

Is there a formula to compress it than clipping it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What would you like the values to be compressed to?